# updating ng-model of one angular js controller from another angular js controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Angular Experts,

I am new to Angular Js and trying to update input in one controller with value from the input in another controller. I am not sure whether it is even possible or not?

I have created js fiddle link just to give an idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/MwK4T/

In this example when you enter a value in controller 2's input, and click 'Set Value it does update biding with `<li></li>` but does't not update input of the controller 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think a search for "communication between Angular controllers" may help you here. It should reveal a few ways, but a fairly standard one would be to have the model provided by a service that is injected into both controllers.

Comment: Thanks Michal ... I made my solution as below ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I made it working using $broadcast. And it is working like a charm.

I did something like this.

```
App.controller('Ctrl1', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('msgid', msg);
});

App.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('msgid', function(event, msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: This worked great for me.  Wish I could give you more than one +1!

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be to use the service, we need to avoid the event as much we can, see this

```
var app= angular.module('testmodule', []);
app.controller('QuestionsStatusController1',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, myservice) {
       $scope.myservice = myservice;   
    }]);

app.controller('QuestionsStatusController2',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, myservice) {
      $scope.myservice = myservice;
    }]);

app.service('myservice', function() {
      this.xxx = "yyy";
    });
```

Check the [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DbBp60AgfbmGpgvwtnpU?p=preview)